# Disable Facebook Feed Dialog's redirect functionality after Send/Cancel buttons are clicked

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ui

Here is how I implement Facebook Feed Dialog to my page:
**HTML tag:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=***************"; 
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

FB.init({
    appId: '***************', 
    display: 'popup',
    status: true, 
    cookie: true, 
    xfbml: true, 
    oauth: true,
    method: 'send'
});
```

**Send button:**

```
<a onclick="javascript:twitter(this); return false;" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?display=popup&app_id=***************&name=<name>&link=<link>&redirect_uri=<uri>">
    <div class="fb-container"></div>
</a>
```

Here I am using Twitter's popup script because `display:popup` doesn't work, don't know why.

However the popup appears and I send the feed. But then I am redirected to `redirect_uri`. I don't want this. I just want to close the popup after clicking Send or Cancel button. I tought something like detecting if a button is clicked and then try `window.close;` but no success because it is a new window (the popup).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are currently using the “direct URL” version of the dialog – and that will always redirect.

If you want it in a popup, that will just close itself after use, then call the dialog by using FB.ui, as in the example in the dialog’s documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: I found the answer yesterday but thanks. That is the solution.

Comment: Does it work without redirecting? As far as I've seen in many places, Feed Dialog always redirect.